# Ipad and CSS attribute overflow

Tags: html, css, ipad, overflow

I tried to add right scroll in `div`. This works in most browsers, but not properly when using iPad Safari. Does the iPad not suported this `css` attribute?

I prepared test html. It do not work too.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .ounner {
                border: solid 1px red;
                width:300px;
                height: 500px;
                overflow:scroll ;
            }
            .inner{
                border: solid blue 1px;
                height: 700px;
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ounner">
            <div class="inner">
                sdsd
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: iOS Safari doesn't display scroll-bars on elements. To show hidden content requires a two-finger drag. This is also true on large code samples here on Stackoverflow. And, frankly, an irritation (certainly on iPhone).

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto` and `overflow: scroll` are supported on MobileSafari, but since scrollbars are not used on iOS, to scroll these areas one must use two fingers.

There is a JavaScript library called [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) that handles touch events and implements one-finger momentum scrolling manually; perhaps that would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

I have used css:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

and scrolling works with 1 finger as well (iPad 2, iOS 5.1.1).

Hope it helps, Filip